# Meu vídeo do FlexSlider está iniciando automaticamente, mas eu não quero isso!

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, flexslider

Eae galera, beleza?

Estou passando por um problema implementei um slider de vídeo em um site que estou fazendo, mas este slider está reproduzindo os vídeos contidos nele automaticamente, e eu não sei como tirar isso, já tentei de várias formas, colocando como "false", os "animation","animationLoop" etc. Mas não estou conseguindo.

Estou usando o Flexslider para fazer isso!

Segue abaixo meu código em JS e também no HTML

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Código em JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

$(".flexslider-video")    
.flexslider({
  animation: false,
  useCSS: false,
  animationLoop: false,
  smoothHeight: true,
  video: false,
```

});

});

Código no HTML:

```
<div class="flexslider-video">           
<div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 286.333px;">
    <ul class="slides" style="width: 400%; margin-left: -570px;">
        <li class="" data-thumb-alt="" style="width: 570px; margin-right: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <iframe id="player_0" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8A6OqHd6dPY" width="600" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        </li>
        <li data-thumb-alt="" class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 570px; margin-right: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <iframe id="player_1" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8A6OqHd6dPY" width="600" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="">
            1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="flex-active">
            2
        </a>
    </li>
</ol>
<ul class="flex-direction-nav">
    <li class="flex-nav-prev">
        <a class="flex-prev" href="#" tabindex="-1">
            Previous
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-nav-next">
        <a class="flex-next flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1">
            Next
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

O video não tem nada haver com o slide, só esta contido dentro dele, você poderia por qualquer coisa dentro do slide, esperar que o slide controle além do que ele foi programado para fazer não faz sentido, então obviamente "animation" e "animationLoop" são configuração da transição de slides e elementos animados do proprio slide

As urls que usou de video também nem deveriam funcionar, creio que o youtube bloquearia elas, já que são origens diferentes, o correto seria usar as URLs neste formato fornecido pela propria YOUTUBE:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID
```

Ficando:

```
    <li class="" data-thumb-alt="" style="width: 570px; margin-right: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <iframe id="player_0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8A6OqHd6dPY" width="600" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </li>
    <li data-thumb-alt="" class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 570px; margin-right: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <iframe id="player_1" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8A6OqHd6dPY" width="600" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </li>
```

Por padrão o autoplay deve estar "desligado", mas se não estiver (não tive como testar) use o `autoplay=0`, assim:

```
    <li class="" data-thumb-alt="" style="width: 570px; margin-right: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <iframe id="player_0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8A6OqHd6dPY?autoplay=0" width="600" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </li>
    <li data-thumb-alt="" class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 570px; margin-right: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <iframe id="player_1" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8A6OqHd6dPY?autoplay=0" width="600" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </li>
```

**Agora**, se ainda esta iniciando o video é porque esta ocorrendo quando você esta clicando no slide para o proximo ou anterior talvez e não é questão de automatico, é na verdade iniciado pelo "clique", mesmo que a intenção seja navegar no slide, isso logo tem que ser ajustado com JS+CSS para bloquear certas ações forçar outras e no iframe ainda terá que aplicar o parametro `&origin=URL_DO_SEU_SITE`, mas não vou formular um exemplo disto pois pode ser que nem seja o seu problema.